# How can I create a command line tool to do this from this code

Tags: python

Suppose the code is stored as `'__main__.py'` under my project's root. And I want to be able to run the code at command line as:

```
 processor [arg1 arg2 ...]
```

When I tried to run it at command line:

```
processor
```

it shows:

```
bash: processor: command not found
```

How to make this code to be runnable with the command 'processor ...'? I saw some similar others' code, but can't get it to work.

```
def create_argument_parser() -> argparse.ArgumentParser:
        """Parse all the command line arguments."""

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            prog="processor",
            formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
            description="Some helpful info...",
        )

        parser.add_argument(
            "--version",
            action="store_true",
            default=argparse.SUPPRESS,
            help="Print installed version",
        )

        ...

        return parser


    def main() -> None:

        arg_parser = create_argument_parser()
        cmdline_arguments = arg_parser.parse_args()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: This is not strictly related to python. Is OS dependent, and the procedure would be (roughly) the same whatever language you use. What is your operative system?

Comment: Mac or Linux or Windows. Let's start with Mac

Comment: @StuartBuckingham answer works for Mac and Linux. You can also read [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41542/adding-a-new-executable-to-the-path-environment-variable). I do not know about Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

Create an alias in your ~/.bashrc file:
    `alias process='python /path/to/the/script'`

Or

- Add the project to the $PATH variable (again in the ~/.bashrc file)
  `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/the/script/parent/directory`
- And change permissions to allow the script to be run
  `chmod +x script`
- Add #!/bin/python to the top of the script
- Then you can call the script by just typing the name of the script, in your case `__init__.py`

Comment: I want to just run "processor", not '__init__.py'

Comment: You could also point out that `__main__.py` can be safely remaned into `processor` (yes, even without the .py extension) if it is the main script to be called.